# How do I read values from property file in Blueprint XML for JBoss Fuse?

Tags: java, apache-camel, jbossfuse

How can I read values from the property file in Blueprint XML for JBoss Fuse?

Currently, I am reading like below, but I want to read from a property file. Can I use Spring BridgePropertyPlaceholoder to achieve it?

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="connections" update-
strategy="reload">
<cm:default-properties>
<cm:property name="xyz" value="http://xx.xx.x.x:x0x0/xxx/yyy"/>
<cm:property name="pqr" value="http://xx.xx.x.x:x0x0/xxx/yyy"/>
<cm:property name="lmn" value="mnopqr"/>
</cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `blueprint-ext` and `blueprint-cm` that extends from it, support an external source for properties file, unrelated to the defualt `ConfigAdmin` used location.

It allows you to write something like:

```

```
  <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="mytest"  update-strategy="reload">
<cm:location>file:///whatever/my.properties</ext:location>
  </cm:property-placeholder>
```

```

Se reference in `blueprint-cm` xsd here:

http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.3.0.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Your are already doing it the right way.

`persistent-id` indicates the name of a file in the `etc/` folder of JBoss Fuse. In your case, it is `etc/connections.cfg`. You also have autoreload if someone edits the file.

Be aware that cfg files **are** property files. From: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

> **Properties**
>   Properties are configuration values managed as *key/value pairs*. In each pair, the key and value are both String values. The key identifies, and is used to retrieve, the value, much as a variable name is used to retrieve the variable's value.

Some other specs if you want to be 100% sure: http://kajabity.com/kajabity-tools/java-properties-classes/the-java-properties-file-format/

So you are already reading a property file. Just with a different extension.

**NOTE**:
If you meant you want to read files scattered around the file system to configure your bundles, I **strongly** advise you **not to do it**, you're looking for troubles. Do this *only if you know what you are doing and you have a reason to do it*.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro for a very clear explanation!!! And yes you are right i do have a file called connection.cfg which has values desined for 'xyz' 'pqr' and 'lmn'. But i have a doubt here what is significance of  <cm:default-properties> if i have values defined for xyz, qr and lmn in connection.cfg.

Comment: @Mr.X If `xyz` is not defined in the file, use the value provided in `<cm:property name="xyz" value="xxx"/>`. It's a default value. If the same property exists in connection.cfg file, the value from the file is used.